# Replace Breadcrumb with static message

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I have a flatsome theme website. I need to replace the breadcrumb with a unique message. There are the shop page which shows categories, the sub-categories page, and then the products of that sub-category page. I need to show 3 different messages for those 3 pages instead of the breadcrumb.

I know very little about code so please help me with completed code to copy and paste it in the functional php file within the child theme.

At the moment I managed to replace the breadcrumbs with one message (same message) for the 3 pages, by editing the Breadcrumb.php file (`/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php`) –

```
<?php
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()
 */

if (!defined( 'ABSPATH' )){
  exit;
}


echo " my message";
```

What I need is php code to change [`echo " my message";`] in previous code to specific message for specific page, and to be included in the previous code. Some code like:

```
if page is (shop page or page ID=****) then echo " message one";

 else if (page is category page or page id =****) then  echo " message two",

 else  echo " message three"
```

so the final code will be something like :

```
<?php
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()
 */

if (!defined( 'ABSPATH' )){
  exit;
}


if page is (shop page or page ID=****) then echo " message one";

 else if (page is category page or page id =****) then  echo " message two",

 else  echo " message three"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WordPress function `is_page()` to achieve what you want to do.

```
if (is_page(123)) {
    echo "message one";
} else if (is_page(456)) {
    echo "message two";
} else {
    echo "message three";
}
```

In this example, `123` and `456` are page IDs. `is_page()` takes the following parameters:

> $page
>   (int|string|array) (Optional) Page ID, title, slug, or array of such.

([Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/))